# ¿Como comparar datos de dos tablas utilizando operadores de comparación almacenados?

Tags: sql, sql-server, script

**Edito para Agregar mis soluciones**

Encontré dos soluciones al problema:

1. Basada en SQL Dinámico
2. Con case when

Sin embargo me gustaría una solución que no incluyera SQL Dinámico ni el
hardcode del case when :

```
case when Operador ='=' then 
     when Operador ='<' then 
     when Operador ='>' then 
     when Operador ='>=' then
     when Operador ='<=' then
```

Tengo dos estructuras como sigue (los datos son solo una muestra) :

Una con datos base (contra los cuales se compara)

```
    create table #DatosBase
    (
        ID int identity (1,1),
        numR int,
        ALertCode varchar (10),
        numOp     int,
        OrdenBase int,
        Criterio varchar (50),
        Operador varchar (5),
        ValorBase int
    )

insert into #DatosBase (numR, AlertCode, numOp, OrdenBase, Criterio, Operador, ValorBase)
    select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) numR,    ALertCode, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ALertCode order by AlertCode )numOp,
    DatosBase.OrdenBase, Criterio,           Operador, DatosBase.Valor ValorBase 
    from 
    (             select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 1  OrdenBase, 'ES_CV_Basal                 'Criterio,  '='     Operador,    1     Valor
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 2  OrdenBase, 'Carga_Viral_Basal           '        ,  '='             ,    19 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 3  OrdenBase, 'Dias_CargaViralActual       '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 4  OrdenBase, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_01   '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 5  OrdenBase, 'ES_CV_Basal_01              '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 6  OrdenBase, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_02   '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 7  OrdenBase, 'DiasCVPrevia_02             '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all select    'A_1_<1000 ' ALertCode , 8  OrdenBase, 'Dif_CVe_CVp'                         ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
        union all                                                                                    
                  select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 1  OrdenBase, 'ES_CV_Basal                 '        ,  '='             ,   1        
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 2  OrdenBase, 'Carga_Viral_VIH             '        ,  '>'             ,   1000    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 3  OrdenBase, 'Dias_CargaViralActual       '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 4  OrdenBase, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_01   '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 5  OrdenBase, 'TDias_01                    '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 6  OrdenBase, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_02   '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 7  OrdenBase, 'TDias_02                    '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
        union all select    'A_2_<1000'  ALertCode , 8  OrdenBase, 'Dif_CVe_CVp'                         ,  NULL            ,   NULL 
        union all                                                                                    
                  select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 1     OrdenBase, 'ES_CV_Basal                 '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL        
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 2     OrdenBase, 'Carga_Viral_VIH             '        ,  '>='            ,   1000        
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 3     OrdenBase, 'Dias_CargaViralActual       '        ,  '>='            ,   168     
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 4     OrdenBase, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_01   '        ,  '='             ,   19      
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 5     OrdenBase, 'TDias_01                    '        ,  '>='            ,   168     
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 6     OrdenBase, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_02   '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL        
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 7     OrdenBase, 'TDias_02                    '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL        
        union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 8     OrdenBase, 'Dif_CVe_CVp'                         ,  NULL            ,   NULL                                                                                                         
    )DatosBase
    order by ALertCode, OrdenBase
```

Y otra con datos de comparación :

```
    create table #DatosComparacion
    (
      ID int identity (1,1),
      Orden int, 
      CriterioEvaluacion varchar(50),
      ValorComparacion decimal (10,6)

    )
insert into #DatosComparacion (Orden, CriterioEvaluacion, 
ValorComparacion)
    select Orden, CriterioEvaluacion, Valor
    from        
    (             select 1  Orden,  'ES_CV_Basal'   CriterioEvaluacion, 2       Valor
        union all select 2       ,  'Carga_Viral_VIH'   CriterioEvaluacion, 1001        Valor
        union all select 3       ,  'TDias'             CriterioEvaluacion, 169     Valor
        union all select 4       ,  'Carga_Viral_VIH'   CriterioEvaluacion, 19      Valor
        union all select 5       ,  'TDias'             CriterioEvaluacion, 169     Valor
        union all select 6       ,  'Carga_Viral_VIH'   CriterioEvaluacion, 387     Valor
        union all select 7       ,  'TDias'             CriterioEvaluacion, 265     Valor
        union all select 8       ,  'Dif_CVe_CVp'       CriterioEvaluacion, -0.33   Valor
    )DatosComparacion
```

Con la comparación bajo cierto criterios obtengo una lista resultante para insertar los resultados en una tercera tabla:

```
    create table #AlertaDetectada
    (
        ID int identity (1,1),
        numR int, 
        AlertCode   varchar (10), 
        numOp       int, 
        OrdenBase   int, 
        Criterio    varchar(50), 
        Operador    varchar(5), 
        ValorBase   int,
        Orden       int,
        CriterioEvaluacion varchar (50),
        ValorComparacion decimal(10,6)
    )



    insert into #AlertaDetectada(numR, AlertCode, numOp, OrdenBase, Criterio, Operador, ValorBase, Orden,   CriterioEvaluacion, ValorComparacion)
    select                       numR, AlertCode, numOp, OrdenBase, Criterio, Operador, ValorBase, dc.Orden,CriterioEvaluacion, ValorComparacion
    from #DatosBase db
    left join #DatosComparacion dc
    on db.OrdenBase = dc.Orden
    where db.ValorBase is not null
```

**Solución 1 basada en SQL Dinámico**

```
    select  'select max(AlertaResultante)AlertaResultante  from ( ' + stuff(( select 'union all' + Operacion
    from 
    (   select   stuff(( select  +  concat (   ' ' , Operacion)
        from
        (   
            select numR, AlertCode,   OrdenBase,   concat (iif (numOp = 1 , '  select iif(  ', '  and  ' ),  ValorBase ,  Operador , ' ', ValorComparacion )Operacion
            from 
            ( select numR, AlertCode,   OrdenBase, numOp , ValorBase ,  Operador ,  case when numOp<> 8 then floor( ValorComparacion ) else  cast ( ValorComparacion as float ) end ValorComparacion -- 
              from #AlertaDetectada
            )t  
        )x
        where x.AlertCode =  isc.AlertCode FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')  + '  ,  '+''''+AlertCode+''''+ ', '+ ''''+'0'+ '''' + ' )   AlertaResultante   '   as Operacion
        from #AlertaDetectada isc group by AlertCode         
    )X
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 9, '')  + ' ) Datos'as CamposInforme
```

**Solución 2 Basada en case when**

Las operaciones de suma y conteo se realizan puesto que se deben cumplí todos los criterios para detectar que ese código de alerta el que se activa:

```
select  iif (sum(Resultado)  = row_count , AlertCode, ' ')AlertaDetectada
from
(
    select  numR, AlertCode, numOp, OrdenBase, Criterio, ValorComparacion, OPerador, ValorBase,                         
                    case    when Operador ='=' then iif (ValorComparacion = ValorBase, 1,0) 
                            when Operador ='<' then iif (ValorComparacion < ValorBase, 1,0) 
                            when Operador ='>' then iif (ValorComparacion > ValorBase, 1,0) 
                            when Operador ='>=' then iif (ValorComparacion >= ValorBase, 1,0) 
                            when Operador ='<=' then iif (ValorComparacion <= ValorBase, 1,0)  end Resultado , row_count
    from 
    (

        select  numR, a.AlertCode, Criterio,  OrdenBase, numOp , ValorBase ,  Operador ,  
                case when numOp<> 8 then floor( ValorComparacion ) else  cast ( ValorComparacion as float ) end ValorComparacion , c.row_count 
        from #AlertaDetectada a
        inner join 
        (
                select AlertCode, COUNT(*) AS row_count
                FROM dbo.#AlertaDetectada
                group by  AlertCode
        )c
        on a.AlertCode = c.AlertCode
    )d

)d
group by AlertCode, row_count
```

En ambos casos he logrado obtener el código de la alerta que se debe activar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aun me gustaría una solución sin usar SQL Dinámico o el hardcode de case when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, dejare aquí mis soluciones, quizás le sirvan a alguien.

**Solución 1 basada en SQL Dinámico**

```
select  'select max(AlertaResultante)AlertaResultante  from ( ' + stuff(( select 'union all' + Operacion
from 
(   select   stuff(( select  +  concat (   ' ' , Operacion)
    from
    (   
        select numR, AlertCode,   OrdenBase,   concat (iif (numOp = 1 , '  select iif(  ', '  and  ' ),  ValorBase ,  Operador , ' ', ValorComparacion )Operacion
        from 
        ( select numR, AlertCode,   OrdenBase, numOp , ValorBase ,  Operador ,  case when numOp<> 8 then floor( ValorComparacion ) else  cast ( ValorComparacion as float ) end ValorComparacion -- 
          from #AlertaDetectada
        )t  
    )x
    where x.AlertCode =  isc.AlertCode FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')  + '  ,  '+''''+AlertCode+''''+ ', '+ ''''+'0'+ '''' + ' )   AlertaResultante   '   as Operacion
    from #AlertaDetectada isc group by AlertCode         
)X
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 9, '')  + ' ) Datos'as CamposInforme
```

**Solución 2 Basada en case when**
Las operaciones de suma y conteo se realizan puesto que se deben cumplí todos los criterios para detectar que ese código de alerta el que se activa:

```html
select  iif (sum(Resultado)  = row_count , AlertCode, ' ')AlertaDetectada
from
(
    select  numR, AlertCode, numOp, OrdenBase, Criterio, ValorComparacion, OPerador, ValorBase,                         
                    case    when Operador ='=' then iif (ValorComparacion = ValorBase, 1,0) 
                            when Operador ='<' then iif (ValorComparacion < ValorBase, 1,0) 
                            when Operador ='>' then iif (ValorComparacion > ValorBase, 1,0) 
                            when Operador ='>=' then iif (ValorComparacion >= ValorBase, 1,0) 
                            when Operador ='<=' then iif (ValorComparacion <= ValorBase, 1,0)  end Resultado , row_count
    from 
    (

        select  numR, a.AlertCode, Criterio,  OrdenBase, numOp , ValorBase ,  Operador ,  
                case when numOp<> 8 then floor( ValorComparacion ) else  cast ( ValorComparacion as float ) end ValorComparacion , c.row_count 
        from #AlertaDetectada a
        inner join 
        (
                select AlertCode, COUNT(*) AS row_count
                FROM dbo.#AlertaDetectada
                group by  AlertCode
        )c
        on a.AlertCode = c.AlertCode
    )d

)d
group by AlertCode, row_count
```

Answer (score 1):

No hace falta que uses SQL dinamico
simplemente con CASE WHEN

```
 select a.*, case when operador='=' and valorComparacion=ValorBase then AlertCode
  when operador='<' and  valorComparacion<ValorBase then AlertCode
  when operador='>='  and valorComparacion>=ValorBase then AlertCode
 ELSE ''
END calculo
from(
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by(select null))rn, 
  ALertCode, ca.Orden OrdenConf, Criterio, Operador, ca.Valor ValorBase, ce.Orden, 
CriterioEvaluacion, ce.Valor ValorComparacion
from 
(
      select    'A_<1000 ' ALertCode , 1    Orden, 'ES_CV_Basal                 'Criterio,  '='     Operador,    1     Valor
union all select    'A_<1000 ' ALertCode , 2    Orden, 'Carga_Viral_Basal           '        ,  '='             ,    19 
union all select    'A_<1000 ' ALertCode , 3    Orden, 'Dias_CargaViralActual       '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
union all select    'A_<1000 ' ALertCode , 4    Orden, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_01   '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
union all select    'A_<1000 ' ALertCode , 5    Orden, 'ES_CV_Basal_01              '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
union all select    'A_<1000 ' ALertCode , 6    Orden, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_02   '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
union all select    'A_<1000 ' ALertCode , 7    Orden, 'DiasCVPrevia_02             '        ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
union all select    'A_<1000 ' ALertCode , 8    Orden, 'Dif_CVe_CVp'                         ,  NULL            ,    NULL 
union all                                                                                    
          select    'A_<1000'  ALertCode , 1    Orden, 'ES_CV_Basal                 '        ,  '='             ,   1        
union all select    'A_<1000'  ALertCode , 2    Orden, 'Carga_Viral_VIH             '        ,  '<'             ,   1000    
union all select    'A_<1000'  ALertCode , 3    Orden, 'Dias_CargaViralActual       '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
union all select    'A_<1000'  ALertCode , 4    Orden, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_01   '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
union all select    'A_<1000'  ALertCode , 5    Orden, 'TDias_01                    '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
union all select    'A_<1000'  ALertCode , 6    Orden, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_02   '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
union all select    'A_<1000'  ALertCode , 7    Orden, 'TDias_02                    '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL    
union all select    'A_<1000'  ALertCode , 8    Orden, 'Dif_CVe_CVp'                         ,  NULL            ,   NULL 
union all                                                                                    
          select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 1     Orden, 'ES_CV_Basal                 '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL        
union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 2     Orden, 'Carga_Viral_VIH             '        ,  '>='            ,   1000        
union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 3     Orden, 'Dias_CargaViralActual       '        ,  '>='            ,   168     
union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 4     Orden, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_01   '        ,  '='             ,   19      
union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 5     Orden, 'TDias_01                    '        ,  '>='            ,   168     
union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 6     Orden, 'Carga_Viral_VIH_Previa_02   '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL        
union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 7     Orden, 'TDias_02                    '        ,  NULL            ,   NULL        
union all select    'A_1000'  ALertCode , 8     Orden, 'Dif_CVe_CVp'                         ,  NULL            ,   NULL        

)ca  
left join 
(       
          select 1  Orden,  'ES_CV_Basal'       CriterioEvaluacion, 2       Valor
union all select 2       ,  'Carga_Viral_VIH'   CriterioEvaluacion, 246     Valor
union all select 3       ,  'TDias'             CriterioEvaluacion, 307     Valor
union all select 4       ,  'Carga_Viral_VIH'   CriterioEvaluacion, 527     Valor
union all select 5       ,  'TDias'             CriterioEvaluacion, 278     Valor
union all select 6       ,  'Carga_Viral_VIH'   CriterioEvaluacion, 387     Valor
union all select 7       ,  'TDias'             CriterioEvaluacion, 265     Valor
union all select 8       ,  'Dif_CVe_CVp'       CriterioEvaluacion, -0.33   Valor
) ce
on ca.Orden = ce.Orden
where ca.Valor is not null)a
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, precisamente buscaba no usar case o sql dinamico.